# Bat: Run a command in several folders

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a project folder with a great number of projects inside. Is there a way I can create a bat file which goes into each of these project folders and runs a couple of commands?

What I would like is to automate what I now would do manually:

```
> cd dir1
> command1 arg1 arg2
> command2 arg1 arg2
> cd ..
> cd dir2
> ...
```

Is this possible to automate with a bat file?

Answer (score 1):

Tried to use what I found in [a forum thread](http://forums.techguy.org/software-development/842079-solved-loop-through-dirrectories-batch.html). Seems to work?

```
pushd C:\projects
for /f "Delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad /b') do (
    cd "%%i"
    command1 arg1 arg2
    command2 arg1 arg2
    cd ..
)
popd
```

Not sure I get the `/f "Delims=` part for example though... I'd also like to exclude some directories. Please comment if you know how :)

Comment: A basic method, would be for you to have a file with only the directories you want. Use dir /ad/b to help build the file. dir /ad/b >dirlist    Then use for /f, with the filename, to run commands on each line of the file. e.g. if your file is called dirlist, then use   for /f %f in (dirlist) do (and then the rest).  i'm not sure about the brackets for the body of the for loop and the multi-line aspect, but anyway.

Comment: "delims=" is necessary to do not use delimiters. default delimiter is space character, so if a folder have some space in its name some problems will occurr (like if one directory is "c:\documents and settings\user"; without "delims=", the first delimiter will be the first space after "documents" and the batch will try to access "c:\documents" instead).

Answer (score 0):

You can use all the commands from the command line in BAT file, so I'm not sure what your question is.

Just write a BAT file like this:

```
cd dir1
command1 arg1 arg2
command2 arg1 arg2
cd ..
cd dir2
```

If you have many directories and the commands are always the same, put them in a second BAT script and use a `for` loop:

```
for %%a IN ('dir /b %PROJECT_FOLDER%') do call second_script.bat %%a
```

Check the help for `dir` if you have files and directories in `%PROJECT_FOLDER%`. There should be an option to list only directories.

Comment: Or use gosub and have it all in one script.

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd C:\projects
:: your 'for /f' was correct, but unnecessary
for /d %%i in (*) do call :foo "%%~i"
popd
goto :eof

:foo
    if "%~1"=="junk" goto :eof
    if "%~1"=="unneeded directory" goto :eof

    pushd "%~1"
    command1
    command2
    popd
    goto :eof
```

Alternatively, if you only want to include a few specific directories:

```
for /d %%i in (a b c) do ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to experiment with alternate command lines, TakeCommand (TCMD/TCC) by JPSoft has had an internal to do this since, I think, the 1980s, back when it was NDOS.

I could do del /s *.bak to kill all the bak files, but that will make an attempt in every folder, and fail if no bak files are present.

Enter *global*.

global if exist *.bak del *.bak

Much faster. Goes through every folder, and only issues the delete if the bak files exist.

For personal administration, I get along much better with JPSoft's enhanced command-line. And I've been using it since the 1980's - I don't think they are going anywhere.